# AppEngine dispatch.yaml for SPA and client-side routing

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a Go server where I have an API and a static client `build` folder with a SPA (Single Page Application). Since the SPA should have client-side routing, I must make sure that all paths map to the frontend. For example, `http://myapp.com/djaksfjal` should not show a 404 in the browser, it should always route to the routes in my SPA.

Now I also want to have a backend API, so all requests to `/api` should go to the Go backend.

Question: how do I set this up with AppEngine? I tried with two `app.yaml` files and one `dispatch.yaml` file but can't get it to work.

**client-app.yaml**

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1
service: default

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /*
  static_dir: build
```

**server-app.yaml**

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1
service: test-backend

handlers:
- url: /api/*
  script: _go_app
```

**dispatch.yaml**

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: test-backend
```

**hello.go**
package main

```
import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/api/hello", handle)
        appengine.Main()
}

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, world!")
}
```

Then running `dev_appserver.py server-app.yaml client-app.yaml dispatch.yaml` and going to localhost:8080 where the dispatch server is. However, this doesn't work. The client-side routing takes over everything, ignoring the `/api/hello` route.

**Tested**: localhost:8080/api/hello. **Expecting**: api route reply. **Got**: static client reply

If I change the `client-app.yaml` to not use a `*` then the `/api/hello` route works, but of course the client-side routing does not work because I need *all* routes to go to the client so that it can handle the routing itself (except for the `/api` routes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules order in the `dispatch.yaml` file matters - the first pattern match wins. So you want the `*/api` one first.

Also - if none of the rules pattern matches the request will be routers to the `default` service, no need to add a rule for that.

I also see that you mentioned an `/api/hello` request path - for that to work you may need to expand the `*/api` pattern into `*/api/*`

So I'd use this `dispatch.yaml` file:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: test-backend
```

You also need to expand the `/api` pattern in the `server-app.yaml` file, otherwise `/api/hello` will give a 404:

```
handlers:
- url: /api/*
  script: _go_app
```

Side note: you shouldn't (need to) go to `localhost:8080` - that'll just send you to the default service. Instead note the individual ports that the development server listens to for each module/service, displayed when the server starts.

Comment: Yeah I tested that too and it doesn't work. The problem is that if I change to that dispatch file, I still get the frontend part. I don't even get a 404 or "there is no handler for this route". So it seems like the client yaml is taking over everything even if the dispatch.yaml clearly says "go to the server yaml".

Comment: I also tried explicitly adding the path `*/api/hello` to `dispatch.yaml` and `/api/hello` to `server.yaml` and it still shows the client/frontend on `localhost:8080/api/hello`

Comment: See the side note I just added

Comment: Well on the other ports it does work as expected (8081 and 8082), but I thought the 8080 one was supposed to actually work like the production app will later? That is, it should route according to dispatch. And it doesn't it only shows the client. HOWEVER, it does work with the localhost:8080/api/hello route IF I remove the `/*` from the `client.yaml` as I wrote in the question (but then the client-side routing is broken). So it seems that this specific rule "takes over" everything else.

Comment: And note that 8080 goes to dispatcher, 8081 to test-backend service and 8082 to default service. So going to 8080 should show both backend and frontend according to dispatch.yaml.

Comment: I never used the dispatcher port directly until now :) OK, I can repro what you report with the `*/api` pattern in the dispatch, but it works fine with `*/api/*`. Anyways, things are clobbered now - too many things tried, I lost track. Update your post with the current configs and for what doesn't work: what URL you request and what does the devserver show in the log for that request.

Comment: I updated my question to contain your suggestions :) still getting the client on all routes though, and not getting the api route

Comment: OK, that's odd. Maybe the Go SDK is a bit different, I'm using the Python one... Try deploying the app: if it works fine on GAE then it's an SDK issue.

Comment: Hm, no :/ I tried and it's the same when deploying the app to GAE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167421/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-myone).

Comment: I realized it was actually correct after a while because when I tested I tested in the browser to see the response (html response or api response) but the browser seems to cache stuff for the SPA so I was fooled by that! When doing curl instead I could clearly see the response I actually got, and then it worked as expected.